# Camera2 front camera preview rotation

Tags: android, rotation, orientation, camera2

i am working on camera2 and have got a problem with rotation.
In some devices, when switching to front camera, preview is being rotated 180 degrees. 
Was looking such a "setDefaultOrientation()" method for camera2 but couldn't find it.

Thanks

Comment: What are you using to display your preview? A SurfaceView or a TextureView, or something else?

Comment: I am using GLSurfaceView.  Orientation is fixed in my app, it is landscape, and the problem with rotation, when camera is switched to front, is not on all devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a GLSurfaceView, you're presumably using a SurfaceTexture to map the camera preview stream into a GL texture, and then rendering it.

The image data in the texture is not automatically rotated to be 'upright' - for one, there's no way for the OS to know how you're going to render your texture.

However, the SurfaceTexture has a [getTransformMatrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html#getTransformMatrix%28float[]%29) call, which when connected to the camera2 API, will give you the necessary transform from the camera's orientation to the device's *native* orientation (typically portrait for phones, landscape for tablets, but not always).  You'll then have to add the transform from the native orientation to your app's orientation to this matrix, and then apply the combined matrix transform to adjust the preview image.

Comment: Thanks Eddy, i did so and problem resolved, but it cause in wrong rotation of  old Camera preview (below API 21). Is there any additional solution for that ?

Comment: For the old camera API, you need to use the setDisplayOrientation call (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation%28int%29); there's sample code in the docs that sets the full transform (don't need to additionally account for app orientation).

Comment: @user0770 Can you please share the piece of code? I am also get stucked with the same issue.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/google/cameraview which uses a TextureView, which is more or less the same, and specifically how it sets up the transform matrix: https://github.com/google/cameraview/blob/master/library/src/main/api14/com/google/android/cameraview/TextureViewPreview.java#L109

Comment: @siva 14 , sure here a part of it:
private SurfaceTexture mSurfaceTexture;
new it with created texture id:
mSurfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(mCameraTexture.getTextureId());
set a listener:
mSurfaceTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener(this);
and get matrix of it:
mSurfaceTexture.getTransformMatrix(mTransformM);
where mTransformM is new float[16];

don't forget to call mSurfaceTexture.updateTexImage() where needed.
Hope this will help.

Answer (score -1):

you can set the correct image rotation in `CaptureRequest` object while capturing an image in `CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback` using `CameraCharacterisitics`

```
CameraCharacterisitics cameraCharacteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
```

like this.

```
private CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback sessionStateCallback = new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
@Override
public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
  captureSession = session;
  try {
    CaptureRequest.Builder builder = session.getDevice().createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
    builder.addTarget(imageReader.getSurface());
    builder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION));
    session.capture(builder.build(), null, backgroundHandler);
  } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
    Log.d("tag", e.getMessage());
  }
}

@Override
public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
}
};
```

Comment: this is for captured image, i need for preview

Answer (score -3):

you can try this code for open your camera

I hope this will help

```
public void startPreview() {
    try {
        Log.i(TAG, "starting preview: " + started);

        // ....
        Camera.CameraInfo camInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraIndex, camInfo);
        int cameraRotationOffset = camInfo.orientation;
        // ...

        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        Camera.Size previewSize = null;
        float closestRatio = Float.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetPreviewWidth = isLandscape() ? getWidth() : getHeight();
        int targetPreviewHeight = isLandscape() ? getHeight() : getWidth();
        float targetRatio = targetPreviewWidth / (float) targetPreviewHeight;

        Log.v(TAG, "target size: " + targetPreviewWidth + " / " + targetPreviewHeight + " ratio:" + targetRatio);
        for (Camera.Size candidateSize : previewSizes) {
            float whRatio = candidateSize.width / (float) candidateSize.height;
            if (previewSize == null || Math.abs(targetRatio - whRatio) < Math.abs(targetRatio - closestRatio)) {
                closestRatio = whRatio;
                previewSize = candidateSize;
            }
        }

        int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        int degrees = 0;
        switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            degrees = 0;
            break; // Natural orientation
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            degrees = 90;
            break; // Landscape left
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            degrees = 180;
            break;// Upside down
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            degrees = 270;
            break;// Landscape right
        }
        int displayRotation;
        if (isFrontFacingCam) {
            displayRotation = (cameraRotationOffset + degrees) % 360;
            displayRotation = (360 - displayRotation) % 360; // compensate
                                                                // the
                                                                // mirror
        } else { // back-facing
            displayRotation = (cameraRotationOffset - degrees + 360) % 360;
        }

        Log.v(TAG, "rotation cam / phone = displayRotation: " + cameraRotationOffset + " / " + degrees + " = "
                + displayRotation);

        this.camera.setDisplayOrientation(displayRotation);

        int rotate;
        if (isFrontFacingCam) {
            rotate = (360 + cameraRotationOffset + degrees) % 360;
        } else {
            rotate = (360 + cameraRotationOffset - degrees) % 360;
        }

        Log.v(TAG, "screenshot rotation: " + cameraRotationOffset + " / " + degrees + " = " + rotate);

        Log.v(TAG, "preview size: " + previewSize.width + " / " + previewSize.height);
        parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
        parameters.setRotation(rotate);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        camera.startPreview();

        Log.d(TAG, "preview started");

        started = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is for android.hardware.camera, my question is for android.hardware.camera2.

Comment: try this code for help you 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/7b6aac1a749c6b2b0a5710e0fd5866ea3c24e12f/tests/tests/hardware/src/android/hardware/camera2/cts/testcases/Camera2MultiViewTestCase.java
and this demo
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Raw
and
https://github.com/MrTillis/Camera2Basic